# Easy way declare two dimension array only knowing one element size with malloc?

Tags: c

How can I declare a two dimensional array only knowing one size of the array. I know the are two columns but don't know how many rows there are. What's a simple way to declare a CHAR bi-dimensional array with malloc.

```
char array[2][?];
```

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: `char* array[2]` and then `malloc` for the second dimension

Comment: @masoud what'd the second part of the declaration with malloc be like?

Comment: I guess: `for (int i=0; i<2; i++) { arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * N); }`

Comment: you can't use `malloc` if you don't know how many rows you want to allocate ...

Comment: As previously pointed out by someone else, you are likely asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please provide information about the underlying problem you want to solve. There probably is a better solution than attempting to do what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't mind that the first index represents the unknown dimension you can declare it as "a pointer to an array of two strings":

```
char *(*array)[2];
```

and allocate it in run time as

```
array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array));
```

where n is the variable holding the actual size of the array.

Then you can use it as an ordinary array. For example:

```
array[n-1][0] = "foo";
array[n-1][1] = "bar";
```